# Python 2.7: Remove subdomains from list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list with about 1,300,000 items.  For example, ['.a', '.b.a', '.c.b', '.f.c.b'].

I'd like to remove subdomains (e.g. '.b.a' and '.f.c.b' in the list above).

I'm a newbie.  I am trying to learn about speed.  Following are my attempts, which seem slow.  Any suggestions:

```
# create separate lists, perhaps that is faster
a1 = []
b2 = []
c3 = []
d4 = []
e5 = []
f6 = []
for i in dupesgone:
    j = i.count('.')
    if j == 1:
        a1.append(i)
    elif j == 2:
        b2.append(i)
    elif j == 3:
        c3.append(i)
    elif j == 4:
        d4.append(i)
    elif j == 5:
        e5.append(i)
    else:
        f6.append(i)

for a in a1:
    la = -len(a)
    for b in b2:
        if a == b[la:]:
            b2.remove(b)
    for c in c3:
        if a == c[la:]:
            c3.remove(c)
    for d in d4:
        if a == d[la:]:
            d4.remove(d)
    --snip--

# how about this, is this faster
[b2.remove(b) for b in b2 for a in a1 if a == b[-len(a):]]
[c3.remove(c) for c in c3 for a in a1 if a == c[-len(a):]]
[d4.remove(d) for d in d4 for a in a1 if a == d[-len(a):]]
[e5.remove(e) for e in e5 for a in a1 if a == e[-len(a):]]
[f6.remove(f) for f in f6 for a in a1 if a == f[-len(a):]]
```

Should I create a dictionary?  Would that be faster?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `a == b[-len(a):]` might be more clearly expressed as `b.endswith(a)`, you shouldn't use list comprehensions for side effects, and you should try to reduce the duplication. If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Instead of asking us which of two pieces of code that you have written is faster... why don't you measure them yourself?

Comment: Do you want `.b.a` to result  in `.b` or should it rather be neglected?

Comment: "b.endswith(a)" sounds smart, thanks.  I am not trying to find out which is faster, but learn if I am missing something big and learn how to deal with large lists efficiently.  I want the final list to be ['.a', '.c.b'], in other words, I want sub-domains removed.  Thanks all!

Comment: Reverse every item, as suggested by Malvolio below, is the type of solution I was looking for.  The speedup is likely 1000x, but I have not tested the actual times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a practical matter, I think the fastest algorithm would be to

1. Reverse every item (so ".b.c" becomes "c.b.")
2. Sort the list
3. Loop through the list with an idea of the "current" item.  If the next item on the list starts with (i.e. is a subdomain of) of the current item, the next item is added to the output list and becomes the current item.
4. Reverse each item on the output list

Here is an untested sketch of the code:

```
def reverse(s):
  return s[::-1]

r = map(reverse, devgone)
r.sort()
ci = None
out = []
for ni in r:
  if not ci or not ni.startswith(ci):
     out.append(ni)
     ci = ni
return map(reverse, out)
```

Comment: This is shockingly fast!  Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 2):

It is often faster just to create a new list than to remove items that don't match:

```
dupesgone = [domain for domain in dupesgone if domain.count(".") == 1]
```

Comment: Despite of filtering based on `len(domain) == 2` this approach would also take care of domains like `.abc` or `.abc.def` since it counts the occurences of `.`.